# Setting values from radio buttons generated with map in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, radio-button

I am trying to :

1. generate radio buttons from a constant array using Map in react
2. let user select one and set the state with handleChange()

With the following code I was able to achieve 1, but for some reason when I try to display with handleChange() I see it is an empty string.

Could you please help me ?

Thanks

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const members = ["Araki", "Ibata", "Fukutome", "Woods", "Alex", "Tatsunami"];

export default class MyRadio extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      lastName: "",
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    console.log("handleChange() e:" + e.target.value);

    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  }
 

  render() {
    console.log("render");
    return (
      <form>
        <div>
          {members.map((item) => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <label htmlFor={item.name}> {item}</label>
              <input
                name="lastName"
                key={item.name}
                id={item.name}
                value={item.name}
                type="radio"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this workable solution you have to change the **members** as follow

```
const members = [{name: "Araki", name: "Ibata", ...}];
```

array should be a object array with each object has name property because in the **map** you are expecting name should be there as `item.name`.

Or either you have to change the loop without `item.name` you have to use `item`

```
{members.map((item) => (
    <React.Fragment>
          <label htmlFor={item}> {item}</label>
          <input
            name="lastName"
            key={item}
            id={item}
            value={item}
            type="radio"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
    </React.Fragment>
))}
```

Comment: After trying out I see this warning: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. It's weird because I set key = {item}

Comment: key sohuld be in react.fragment